# Return to calling page instead of dashboard after Login (Laravel 8)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

In my Laravel 8 Application link to login route is provided on different locations, i.e., user can login from multiple pages.  By default, after login user is redirected to the dashboard. I am looing for a way to return the user to same page from where he clicked on the login button.
I am using Laravel with Jetstream and Livewire.  The documentation says that I can do this by changing "public const HOME = '/ dashboard';" to the desired destination, but in my case the destination can be more than a single url.
I tried 'redirect()->back()' in place of '/ dashboard' but it does not work.  Please help what change is required.

Comment: Can you add the code of your `LoginController`?

Comment: By default Jetstream has no login controller.  And manually I have not created one

Answer (score 0):

Save previous url when you redirect user to login page and after authentication of user redirect him on same page with the session you saved. Try this:

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
     session(['link' => url()->previous()]);
     return view('auth.login');
}


protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
     return redirect(session('link'));
}
```